# Problems installing Julia language

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, 16.10, julia-lang

I'm following instructions from [here](http://julialang.org/downloads/platform.html) (see Ubuntu section). It says me to do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:staticfloat/juliareleases
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:staticfloat/julia-deps
sudo apt-get update
```

But then the command

```
sudo apt-get install julia
```

Gives me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 julia : Depends: libcholmod1.7.1 but it is not installable or
              libcholmod2.1.2 but it is not installable or
              libcholmod3.0.6 but it is not installable
     Depends: libumfpack5.4.0 but it is not installable or
              libumfpack5.6.2 but it is not installable or
              libumfpack5.7.1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using Xubuntu 16.10.

Can you please help me to understand what is going on and how to solve it?

Comment: For the record, Julia is available in official Ubuntu repositories, there's no need to add external PPA unless you rely on the newest version of the language

Answer (score 8):

For future users: get the newer version/a working link from https://julialang.org/downloads/

```
# go to your user folder
cd ~
# get julia
wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
# extract the file (eXtract File as options)
tar xf julia-1.3.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
# Create a shortcut (a soft link) that's places in a globally accessible folder
sudo ln -s ~/julia-1.3.0/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

Now you can run `julia` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have broken packages. To fix the problem, you might want to try entering this into the terminal:

```
sudo sh -c "apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean"
```

Also enter this into the terminal:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This should fix up your broken packages. Now try installing Julia again.